# How to join to the same table with many conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Product table:

```
+------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| product_id | product_brand_id  |    product_group_id|
+------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|    19335   |            10000  |    10002           |   
|    19336   |            10000  |    10002           | 
|    19358   |            10001  |    10003           |    
+------------+-------------------+------------+-------+
```

Because I have Product Type and Product Brand in the same table like this.

Picklist_Item table:

```
+------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
| id         | picklist_id       | picklist_code  |    piit_name   |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
|    00001   |            100    |    10000       |    TOYOTA      |
|    00002   |            100    |    10001       |    HONDA       |
|    00003   |            101    |    10002       |      BODY      |  
|    00004   |            101    |    10003       |    CHEMICAL    |  
+------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

picklist_id for tell this is Product Brand or Product Type

column picklist_code is Brand and Group id

Picklist table:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
| picklist_id       | pick_name         |   
+-------------------+-------------------+
|    100            |       BRAND       | 
|    101            |       TYPE        |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The result that I want.

```
+------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+
| product_id | product_brand_id  |    brand_name  |  product_group_id   |  type       |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+
|    19335   |            10000  |    TOYOTA      |    10002            |  BODY       |
|    19336   |            10000  |    TOYOTA      |    10002            |  BODY       |
|    19358   |            10001  |    HONDA       |    10003            |  CHEMICAL   |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

this is my code

```
  SELECT Product.product_id , Product.product_brand_id  , Picklist_Item.piit_name as Brand_name,  Product.product_group_id, Picklist_Item.piit_name as Type
  FROM Product
  LEFT JOIN Picklist_Item ON Product.product_brand_id = Picklist_Item.picklist_code
  LEFT JOIN Picklist_Item ON Product.product_group_id = Picklist_Item.picklist_code
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same picklist_code with different picklist_id, or is picklist_code unique?

Comment: Do you have more than just 2 picklist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are joining to the same table twice, you need to give the two instances different aliases so that they can be distinguished from each other. This query will give you the results you want:

```
SELECT Product.product_id, Product.product_brand_id, p1.piit_name as Brand_name, Product.product_group_id, p2.piit_name as Type  
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Picklist_Item p1 ON Product.product_brand_id = p1.picklist_code
LEFT JOIN Picklist_Item p2 ON Product.product_group_id = p2.picklist_code
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8joP157rYqoV8g6P8KrLS5/0)